# What is the best accessible and W3C valid way to code a one simple search input box with image button?

Tags: html, css, validation

What is the best accessible and W3C HTML 4.01 strict valid way to code a one simple search input box with image button(to do search)?

like this

[alt text http://stashbox.org/776012/110024185259-My-Desktop.png](http://stashbox.org/776012/110024185259-My-Desktop.png)

accessible and W3C HTML 4.01 strict valid both.

Comment: So the magnifier is the submit button?

Comment: @gumbo - yes. serch should work from "enter" and pressing by "magnifier" both

Answer (score 3):

`<span class="search"><input type="text" ...><input type="image" ...></span>`
Where those are the only non-hidden inputs in the form (to get the submit-on-enter behavior).

`.search{border:1px solid silver; display:inline-block;}`
`.search input{border:0; background:transparent;}`
... give or take (-moz-)border-radius and background on .search.